# Wordpress TinyMCE Image upload issue

Tags: php, wordpress, tinymce

I am using the WP_editor function to add some content to a custom database table, the only problem I have come across is with images, TinyMCE is adding some unnecessary charctars which is preventing the images from being displayed.

Example:

```
src="\"http://localhost:8888/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2014/04/dscn7122-300x225.jpg\""
```

Should be:

```
src="http://localhost:8888/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2014/04/dscn7122-300x225.jpg"
```

Answer (score 0):

while building the src just use str_replace for a quick fix.

```
str_replace('\"','',image_src)
```

This is the quick fix without editing the plugin code.

Hope this helps you.

Comment: Where should I add this as surely the building is done within the WP_editor function?

Comment: You can add where the image is rendered. If its in the WP_editor, then  while displaying the content you can use this. Instead of image_src you use the the_content() function, so wherever the matching quotes comes in image it will replace with empty literals. Try this